# pop up shows after button clicked

Tags: jquery, popup

on the website there is an existing pop up. I need to show my second pop #pop-up once they click on the button #closeModal. I am not familiar with Jquery yet so I need some help please.

This is the existing pop up.

```
<div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="socialModalCenterTitle" class="modal fade hidden-xs" id="socialModalCenter" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p class="up-to-date">
                    Stay up to date with the Team.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button data-dismiss="modal" id="closeModal" type="button">Sign up later</button></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the pop up I want to show once the button of the first pop up is clicked

```
<div class="container" id="pop-up" style="display: none">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <a onclick="document.getElementById('pop-up').style='display:none!important;'; localStorage.setItem('pop-up','shown');"><button class="close" type="button"><span>&times;</span></button></a>
            <p>
                This is the new pop up</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if(localStorage.getItem('pop-up') != 'shown'){
            $("#pop-up").delay(2000).show();
            //localStorage.setItem('pop-up','shown');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this is what you might be looking for:

```
$('#closeModal').click(function(){
    $('#pop-up').show();
});
```

Snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/tshenolo/85pmfvje/3/